# Is there a way to keep track of unopened/unchecked files?

Tags: windows, tracking

I'm looking for a way to keep track of unopened/unchecked received/downloaded files via various means, browsers, torrents, DC++, hosting sites, etc.

Let's say that I'm a bit overwhelemed, and because you don't download something instantly, and you have to wait, days, even weeks sometimes, I forget to check all the downloaded/received files.

Comment: Which system are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Many programs allow you to configure separate directories for in-process and completed downloads. Even browsers allow you to specify a default downloads directory. Perhaps manually moving checked/opened files out of your downloads directory can be a solution?